# enum of Color Codes

Tags: java, android, enums, colors

I have a Color enum :

```
public enum Color {
    YELLOW(0), RED(1), GREEN(2), BLUE(3), GRAY(4), CYAN(5), BLACK(6), MAGENTA(7);

    int colorCode;

    Color(int colorCode) {
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
    }

    public int getColorCode() {
        return this.colorCode;
    }

    public Color getColor(int colorCode) {
        return Color.this.colorCode;
    }
}
```

I want to return a Color depending of colorCode, but I got a exception

```
incompatibles Types int and Color
```

How can I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Enums have "ordinal" number associated with each value. Ordinal corresponds to "definition index", so you can simply write `Color.values()[index]` to get `Color` at specified index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
public static Color getColor(int colorCode) {
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
        if (c.getColorCode() == colorCode)
            return c;
    }
    return NOT_DEFINE;
}
```

Note I defined another enum `NOT_DEFINE(8)` in case the code not exit and return it in the end of the getColor.

---

But I would like to create a Map which hold `Map<colorCode, Color>` so you can get the colors easily with key without looping over the values of the enum each time

```
static Map<Integer, Color> mapOfColord = new HashMap<>();

static {
    Map<Integer, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();
    for (Color color : Color.values()) {
        colors.put(color.colorCode, color);
    }
    mapOfColord = Collections.unmodifiableMap(colors);
}
```

Or you can stick with the first method which take the key and return the Color like so :

```
private static Map<Integer, Color> mapOfColord = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (Color color : Color.values()) {
        mapOfColord.put(color.colorCode, color);
    }
}

public static Color getColor(Integer key) {
    return mapOfColord.get(key);
}
```

So you can get the Color like this for example :

```
int key = 3;
Color blue = Color.mapOfColord.get(key);
```

Or :

```
Color blue = Color.getColor(key);
```

---

Thank you [@Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) for the information, I appreciate it.

Comment: You should make that method static too. And in any case, you shouldn't refer to `NOT_EXIST` via this.

Comment: you don't want it to be an instance method. That would mean you would need an instance of Color on which to invoke the method to get an instance of `Color` from an int.

Comment: You similarly want the Map to be static, in order that you don't have an copy of that map for every enum value.

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L and  Andy Turner it helps me a lot.

Comment: @AndyTurner I can't make the Map static It will gives you `illegal reference to static field from initializer`

Comment: @YCL_L given that it is a static field that you are initializing, use a static initializer.

Comment: @AndyTurner Its my first time that I use that maybe thank you for teaching me that, Is that what you mean?

Comment: @YCF_L you should also either make the map unmodifiable, or only expose a method to get the Color. Otherwise you can change the values in the map (e.g. remove them all using `Color.mapOfColord.clear()`).

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner for the information I really appreciate it, what should I do more :)